# Where to put application.conf in Play for Scala standalone?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-3.0

I am using Slick in Play for Scala standalone (i.e. not web application). Where to put the application.conf file so Slick takes the database configuration?

I tried in main/resources/application.conf but it doesn't work. This is my directories structure:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting
>   found for key 'dbControl'

And appplication.conf:

```
dbControl = {
  url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/control0001"
  driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
  user=root
  password=xxxx
}
```

Comment: try to put another dummy config, and try to access it. Just to check if it can't read the config file, or it's just the key it's wrongly defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, putting application.conf in src/main/scala folder directly.